# R ggplot internal overwrite of plot object

Tags: r, object, ggplot2

I suddenly encounter a dreadful problem with `ggplot`, where my original plot object is somehow internally overwritten.

The plot `p`, is based on a subset `s` of a data frame `d`. When `s` is altered, the plot `p` changes automatically:

```
library(ggplot2)

#data
d<-data.frame(
  t=c(-1, 2, -3,  4, -5,  6),
  order=1:6
)
#subset data
s<-d[4:6,]
#create plot
p<-
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x=s$t,y=1:nrow(s)),size=3,col="black")  

#first plot print
p

#back to original data
s<-d

#second plot print
p #plot changed according to the new data frame
```

*First plot* gives: 
[image: first plot]

*Second plot* gives: 
[image: second plot]

Comment: Based upon the behaviour it looks that the plot is generated upon request to show, but that the assignment is kept to the variable. Don't think that's a bug though. Maybe you can find something at [GGplot2 Issues](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues)

Comment: This is a problem with the way the OP is trying to hack ggplot2, _not_ with ggplot2. Please do not file any issue as this is expected behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're an expert in ggplot2 and need to do something pretty complex, you should *never*, *ever*, *ever* use vectors vs mapped columns as `aes()` parameters and should also *really* try to avoid `$` selected columns in `aes()` as well. That's your problem here (it also looks like you're trying to use ggplot2 in the same way as you would use base graphics plotting and that's a path fraught with peril).

```
library(ggplot2)

data.frame(
  t = c(-1, 2, -3,  4, -5,  6),
  order = 1:6
) -> d

s <- d[4:6,]
```

Now, do the proper ggplot2 idiom and add a column with the `y` aesthetic you want to use. I chose the name `idx` somewhat at random since we don't know what you want to do.

```
s$idx <- 1:nrow(s)
```

Now/again, do the proper ggplot2 idiom and pass a data frame into `ggplot()` and map the columns to aesthetics *without* `$`.

```
ggplot(s) +
  geom_point(
    aes(t, idx), size = 3, color = "black"
  ) -> p
```

The issue is that ggplot2 does nothing with the parameters until the chart is constructed. It lazy evaluates them so when you try to plot it *after* you change `s` it's picking up the "new" `s`.

Comment: Solved by a perfect answer... I somehow encountered "lazy evaluates" when I previously searched for a solution. Haven't really understood it dough.